# Which format to use in Garageband?

Tags: garageband

I would like to record my voice, a guitar and an electronic drummer through a mixer into Garageband.

When I click on 'New Project' I am not sure what format (piano, voice, etc.) I should be using. Can you steer me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always start with SongWriter, it sounds like it would suit your needs perfectly. It includes tracks already set up for vocals, drums, keyboards and guitar.